# socket and tkinter not running in sequence

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working on a project to run between 2 raspberry pi's. im finding that when I run Tkinter code with socket code, it will run the socket code first. this is a problem as I would like a screen to show that it is trying to connect to a client, but the menu and Tkinter code only shows up once a connection is made. please can someone help, here is some code:
You can see the GUI ive made by hashing outlines 45, 46, 47 line 45 is the trouble maker.

```
from tkinter import *
import socket as connect
import sys

host = ''
port = 5490

wn = Tk()
wn.geometry('800x450+300+100')
wn.title('Connect 4 Server')

BordF = Frame(wn)
BordF.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
font = 'arial 200'
font2 = 'arial 15'
LeftBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
LeftBorderFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill = Y)
LeftBorderSpacer1 = Label(LeftBorderFrame, text=' ', bg='#93D5FF', font=font)
LeftBorderSpacer1.pack(side=LEFT)
RightBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
RightBorderFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
RightBorderSpacer1 = Label(RightBorderFrame, text=' ', bg='#93D5FF', font=font)
RightBorderSpacer1.pack(side=RIGHT)
TopBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
TopBorderFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill = X)
TopBorderSpacer1 = Label(TopBorderFrame, text='', bg='#93D5FF', font=font2)
TopBorderSpacer1.pack(side=TOP)
BottomBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
BottomBorderFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill = X)
BottomBorderSpacer1 = Label(BottomBorderFrame, text='', bg='#93D5FF', font=font2)
BottomBorderSpacer1.pack(side=BOTTOM)



SwitchF = Frame(BordF)
SwitchF.pack(side=TOP)
ConnGF = Frame(SwitchF)
ConnGF.pack(side=TOP)
InfoL1 = Label(ConnGF, text='Waiting for Connection \n \n ' + connect.gethostbyname(connect.gethostname()), font='arial 20')
InfoL1.pack(side=TOP)

s = connect.socket(connect.AF_INET, connect.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

#
s.listen(1)
conn, adrr = s.accept()
print('Connected to: ' + adrr[0] + ': ' + adrr[1])
#

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: you may have to run socket in seperated thread beacuse `accept()` blocks code and `mainloop()` can't run and it can't display window. And you can't change order because `mainloop()` will block `accept()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `mainloop()` the line of code that shows the GUI is after the connection code. Also `mainloop()` is an endless loop, so any code written after (i.e socket connection) won't happen until the GUI destroys.

**A solution:** You can delay the method using `tk.after()`. This will wait the given number of milliseconds before executing the given method:

```py
from tkinter import *
import socket as connect
import sys

host = ''
port = 5490

def connect():
   s = connect.socket(connect.AF_INET, connect.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.bind((host, port))

   #
   s.listen(1)
   conn, adrr = s.accept()
   print('Connected to: ' + adrr[0] + ': ' + adrr[1])
   #


wn = Tk()
wn.geometry('800x450+300+100')
wn.title('Connect 4 Server')

BordF = Frame(wn)
BordF.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
font = 'arial 200'
font2 = 'arial 15'
LeftBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
LeftBorderFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill = Y)
LeftBorderSpacer1 = Label(LeftBorderFrame, text=' ', bg='#93D5FF', font=font)
LeftBorderSpacer1.pack(side=LEFT)
RightBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
RightBorderFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
RightBorderSpacer1 = Label(RightBorderFrame, text=' ', bg='#93D5FF', font=font)
RightBorderSpacer1.pack(side=RIGHT)
TopBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
TopBorderFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill = X)
TopBorderSpacer1 = Label(TopBorderFrame, text='', bg='#93D5FF', font=font2)
TopBorderSpacer1.pack(side=TOP)
BottomBorderFrame = Frame(BordF, bg='#93D5FF')
BottomBorderFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill = X)
BottomBorderSpacer1 = Label(BottomBorderFrame, text='', bg='#93D5FF', font=font2)
BottomBorderSpacer1.pack(side=BOTTOM)



SwitchF = Frame(BordF)
SwitchF.pack(side=TOP)
ConnGF = Frame(SwitchF)
ConnGF.pack(side=TOP)
InfoL1 = Label(ConnGF, text='Waiting for Connection \n \n ' + connect.gethostbyname(connect.gethostname()), font='arial 20')
InfoL1.pack(side=TOP)

#wait two seconds before connecting
wn.after(2000, connect)

wn.mainloop()
``
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/